# Closure inconsistency between parallel and sequential execution

Tags: go

I have attempted to write a generic function that can execute functions in parallel or sequentially. While testing it, I have found some very unexpected behavior regarding closures. In the code below, I define a list of functions that accept no parameters and return an error. The functions also use a for loop variable in a closure but I'm using the trick of defining a new variable within the loop in an attempt to avoid capture.

I'm expecting that I can call these functions sequentially or concurrently with the same effect but I'm seeing different results. It's as if the closure variable is being captured but only when run concurrently.

As far as I can tell, this is not the usual case of capturing a loop variable. As I mentioned, I'm defining a new variable within the loop. Also, I'm not running the closure function within the loop. I'm generating a list of functions within the loop but I'm executing the functions after the loop.

I'm using go version go1.8.3 linux/amd64.

```
package closure_test

import (
    "sync"
    "testing"
)

// MergeErrors merges multiple channels of errors.
// Based on https://blog.golang.org/pipelines.
func MergeErrors(cs ...<-chan error) <-chan error {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    out := make(chan error)

    // Start an output goroutine for each input channel in cs.  output
    // copies values from c to out until c is closed, then calls wg.Done.
    output := func(c <-chan error) {
        for n := range c {
            out <- n
        }
        wg.Done()
    }
    wg.Add(len(cs))
    for _, c := range cs {
        go output(c)
    }

    // Start a goroutine to close out once all the output goroutines are
    // done.  This must start after the wg.Add call.
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(out)
    }()
    return out
}

// WaitForPipeline waits for results from all error channels.
// It returns early on the first error.
func WaitForPipeline(errs ...<-chan error) error {
    errc := MergeErrors(errs...)
    for err := range errc {
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func RunInParallel(funcs ...func() error) error {
    var errcList [](<-chan error)
    for _, f := range funcs {
        errc := make(chan error, 1)
        errcList = append(errcList, errc)
        go func() {
            err := f()
            if err != nil {
                errc <- err
            }
            close(errc)
        }()
    }
    return WaitForPipeline(errcList...)
}

func RunSequentially(funcs ...func() error) error {
    for _, f := range funcs {
        err := f()
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func validateOutputChannel(t *testing.T, out chan int, n int) {
    m := map[int]bool{}
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        m[<-out] = true
    }
    if len(m) != n {
        t.Errorf("Output channel has %v unique items; wanted %v", len(m), n)
    }
}

// This fails because j is being captured.
func TestClosure1sp(t *testing.T) {
    n := 4
    out := make(chan int, n*2)
    var funcs [](func() error)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        j := i // define a new variable that has scope only inside the current loop iteration
        t.Logf("outer i=%v, j=%v", i, j)
        f := func() error {
            t.Logf("inner i=%v, j=%v", i, j)
            out <- j
            return nil
        }
        funcs = append(funcs, f)
    }
    t.Logf("Running funcs sequentially")
    if err := RunSequentially(funcs...); err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    validateOutputChannel(t, out, n)
    t.Logf("Running funcs in parallel")
    if err := RunInParallel(funcs...); err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    close(out)
    validateOutputChannel(t, out, n)
}
```

Below is the output from the test function above.

```
closure_test.go:91: outer i=0, j=0
closure_test.go:91: outer i=1, j=1
closure_test.go:91: outer i=2, j=2
closure_test.go:91: outer i=3, j=3
closure_test.go:99: Running funcs sequentially
closure_test.go:93: inner i=4, j=0
closure_test.go:93: inner i=4, j=1
closure_test.go:93: inner i=4, j=2
closure_test.go:93: inner i=4, j=3
closure_test.go:104: Running funcs in parallel
closure_test.go:93: inner i=4, j=3
closure_test.go:93: inner i=4, j=3
closure_test.go:93: inner i=4, j=3
closure_test.go:93: inner i=4, j=3
closure_test.go:80: Output channel has 1 unique items; wanted 4
```

Any ideas? Is this a bug in Go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always run your tests with -race. In your case, you forgot to recreate `f` on each iteration in `RunInParallel`:

```
func RunInParallel(funcs ...func() error) error {
    var errcList [](<-chan error)
    for _, f := range funcs {

        f := f // << HERE

        errc := make(chan error, 1)
        errcList = append(errcList, errc)
        go func() {
            err := f()
            if err != nil {
                errc <- err
            }
            close(errc)
        }()
    }
    return WaitForPipeline(errcList...)
}
```

As a result, you always launched the last `f` instead of each one.

Comment: Neat, I've never thought of shadowing it over itself like this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to use "-race". It highlighted the problem that you have identified. I suspected that this was a loop capture issue but I was focusing on the wrong loop!

Answer (score 4):

I believe your problem lies in your `RunInParallel` func.

```
func RunInParallel(funcs ...func() error) error {
    var errcList [](<-chan error)
    for _, f := range funcs {
        errc := make(chan error, 1)
        errcList = append(errcList, errc)
        go func() {
            // This line probably isn't being reached until your range
            // loop has completed, meaning f is the last func by the time
            // each goroutine starts. If you capture f
            // in another variable inside the range, you won't have this issue.
            err := f()
            if err != nil {
                errc <- err
            }
            close(errc)
        }()
    }
    return WaitForPipeline(errcList...)
}
```

You could also pass f as a parameter to your anonymous function to avoid this issue.

```
for _, f := range funcs {
    errc := make(chan error, 1)
    errcList = append(errcList, errc)
    go func(g func() error) {
        err := g()
        if err != nil {
            errc <- err
        }
        close(errc)
    }(f)
}
```

[Here](https://play.golang.org/p/5ySIBZ6DjL) is a live example in the playground.